Yocto SRCREV issue
I'm trying to compile a yocto image, in Kirkstone, imx-5.15.71-2.2.0 with a meta-custom but I keep getting this error:
ERROR: twin-1.0-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError("Please set a valid SRCREV for url ['SRCREV_default:pn-twin', 'SRCREV_default', 'SRCREV:pn-twin', 'SRCREV'] (possible key names are git://github.com/eclipse-ditto/ditto.git;protocol=https;branch=main, or use a ;rev=X URL parameter)", 'git://github.com/eclipse-ditto/ditto.git;protocol=https;branch=main')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/bld-xwayland/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/twin/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.871303
ERROR: Task (/opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/sources/meta-custom/recipes-apps/twin/twin.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

The meta-custom contains 2 folders, twin and acapy, where
twin:
https://github.com/bernar0507/Automate-Twin-Process.git
https://github.com/eclipse-ditto/ditto.git
https://github.com/bernar0507/Eclipse-Ditto-MQTT-iwatch-SSL-TCP.git

acapy:
https://github.com/paquino11/Masters-v3.git

I've tried setting the tag to their latest push and HEAD, but I still face this error.
All help is appreciated

The error implies that you have to provide commit hash for each of the repos in the recipe. This way bitbake will know exactly what t checkout from each repo.
SRC_URI = "git://<git-repo1>;protocol=ssh;branch=master;name=repo1
SRC_URI += "git://<gitrepo2>;protocol=ssh;branch=main;name=repo2"

SRCREV_repo1 = "<commit-hash>"
SRCREV_repo2 = "<commit-hash>"

